# Quel est le comparatif de « bienveillant » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, comparatifs

Quelqu’un m’a demandé récemment ce que j’utiliserais comme comparatif de bienveillant. Et de me faire deux suggestions :

- plus bienveillant
- mieux veillant

Depuis, je suis comme le capitaine Haddock qui ne sait pas s’il dort avec la barbe au dessus ou en dessous des couvertures : l’un ne va pas, mais l’autre ne va pas non plus. J’évite la tournure purement et simplement.

Connaissez-vous des exemples d’utilisation de l’un ou l’autre dans la littérature ? Des références qui en parlent ? Je ne trouve rien dans mon Grevisse et je suis parvenu à égarer mon dictionnaire (ça m’apprendra à ranger !)

Comment: Alors il faut couper la barbe, supprimer la couverture, réinventer le monde... dormir en scaphandre, sur le ventre... mais rester bancal n'est pas la solution.

Comment: Il est sans doute plus difficile d'utiliser un comparatif en dehors des constructions comparatives à proprement parler. Hors contexte, les deux propositions semblent de fait étranges.

Comment: je crois que si je devais utiliser "plus bienveillant", j'essaierais de formuler la phrase autrement afin d'amener cela autrement. A condition que ce soit possible évidemment.

Answer (score 5):

Je ne crois pas avoir déjà rencontré *mieux veillant* ([nGram non plus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mieux%20veillant%2C%20mieux-veillant%2C%20mieuxveillant&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)), et serais d'avis que le trouble apparent à "entendre" la séquence interdite *plus bien* n'est qu'une nuisance mineure...

Il faut se résoudre à utiliser **plus bienveillant**, me semble-t-il.

En revanche, ce raisonnement ne tient que pour des mots comme *bienveillant* ou *bienheureux* qui sont d'un seul tenant, pas pour des termes composés comme *bien portant* qui eux donneront des comparatifs avec "mieux".

On pourrait presque élargir la question à l'ensemble des mots qui se construisent sur "bon" ou "bien". Si je vois un homme assez gros, je dirai peut-être qu'il a de l'*embonpoint*. En revanche, en voyant son frère un peu plus gros encore, je ne dirai pas qu'il a de l'*emmeilleurpoint*...

Comment: ps : et sinon, pour *l'autre* question, je dirais "en dessous" (la barbe)

Comment: Pour ajouter un exemple concret, une formulation comme « Paul est plus bienveillant que sa sœur » ne semble pas problématique. Par ailleurs, la prononciation [ply] est sans doute préférable...

Answer (score 2):

*Quelques observations sur l'étymologie*

> **ÉTYMOL. ET HIST.** − *Ca* 1175 subst. « ami » (Benoit, *Ducs de Normandie*, éd. C.
>   Fahlin, 6427); 1267-68 adj. (Brunet Latin, *Trésor*, 80 dans *T.-L.*).
>   Composé de [bien](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bien)*, adv., et de *voillant*, *veillant*, part. prés.
>   a. fr. du verbe [vouloir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vouloir)*, d'après le lat. class. [*bene
>   volens*](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=benevolens).
>
> [ Trésor de la langue française informatisé, TLFi, - [*bienveillant*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bienveillant)  ]

Ça remplace [*bénévolence*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/benevolence). En substantif c'est l'idée de l'*ami*, mais c'est formé avec un participe présent et c'est essentiellement *vouloir le bien de/à quelqu'un*, tel qu'on le trouve au [*DmF*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/bienveillant?idf=dmfXgXrmXbdbf;str=0); *bien* est un substantif ici, on ne dit pas *bien vouloir/vouloir bien (à) quelqu'un*; c'est plutôt un ami *qui veut du bien* (de manière contemporaine surtout dans le sens d'être *attentif*).

---

*Quelques citations*

> Son jour ! l'abolition de toutes souffrances sonores et mouvantes dans la musique plus intense.
>   Son pas ! les migrations plus énormes que les anciennes invasions.
>   Ô lui et nous ! l'orgueil *plus bienveillant* que les charités perdues.
>   Ô monde ! et le chant clair des malheurs nouveaux !
>
> [ Arthur Rimbaud, extrait de [*Génie*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_wuiBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT50&dq=%22plus%20bienveillant%22&pg=PT6#v=onepage&q=%22plus%20bienveillant%22&f=false), ds. [*Illuminations*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Illuminations_%28Rimbaud%29), posthume 1895
>   (1875) ]
>
> ---
>
> Son intelligence des choses s'était agrandie, sa science s'était
>   approfondie et enrichie, son âme était devenue plus sereine, son cœur
>   *plus bienveillant* et plus sensible ; sa volonté à la fois plus modérée, plus forte et plus ferme.
>
> [ Jean Henri Merle d'Aubigné, [*Histoire de la Réformation en Europe
>   au temps de Calvin*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=yRqiO1FVgQEC&dq=%22plus%20bienveillant%22%20-%22le%20plus%22&pg=PA69#v=onepage&q=%22plus%20bienveillant%22%20-%22le%20plus%22&f=false), Volume 7, 1842-1853 ]
>
> ---
>
> [Berrichon] se disposa à remplir celles [fonctions] de convive, et
>   revint se placer à la droite de M Achille Lefort, qui, ainsi que l'avocat se mit en frais pour lui plaire. Ils y réussirent aisément, car
>   *nulle* âme au monde n'est *plus bienveillante* à table que celle du
>   Berrichon.
>
> [ Amantine Aurore Lucile Dupin (*George Sand*), [*Le compagnon du tour
>   de France*](http://archive.org/stream/qeuvresdegeorges1819sand#page/n173/mode/2up/search/%22plus+bienveillante%22), 1840 ]

Answer (score 1):

Ce n'est pas parce qu'il a le mot bien, qu'il a un rapport.

Bienveillant a absolument le même comportement grammatical qu'aurait "veillant" seul si cet adjectif existait.

Ce serait comme dire que malpoli est un comparatif. "Il faudrait inventer meilleurveillant.": non, car le fait qu'il y ait "bien" dans le mot, c'est comme le préfixe "mal" dans malpoli. Est-ce que ça viendrait à l'esprit de quelqu'un de dire "pire-poli"?

On pourrait très bien avoir un antonyme de malpoli qui serait bienpoli.

On dit donc "le plus bienveillant", mais je suis d'accord avec la réponse de cl-r, dire "d'une bienveillance accrue" ou une autre formule du même type est beaucoup mieux, ça ne choque pas l'oreille.
On a tellement l'habitude de tiquer quand on entend "plus bien", mais là c'est un mot, on ne peut pas le déconstruire.

Je ne pense pas qu'aucune règle s'oppose à "plus bienveillant", mais ça peut sembler lourd, selon la phrase. Quand ça risque de choquer l'oreille, le bon usage je pense veut qu'on essaye de paraphraser avec une tournure moins lourde.

Quand on fait une recherche dans les livres sur Google, on trouve cette formule, ça confirme qu'elle n'est pas fautive.

Answer (score 0):

*Bienveillant* et *malveillant* sont des adjectifs intuitivement perçus comme des comparatifs en eux-mêmes.

*Plus pire, davantage mieux*... sont rayés du vocabulaire des premiers mots que les enfants prononcent.

Bien que *plus bienveillant* soit utilisé, c'est une formule soutenue et vieillie ; pour éviter ce qui semble, à l'oreille une tautologie (et qui gène le capitaine Haddock), peut-être utiliser un :

> *nom* : « une bienveillance accrue, une malveillance délétère ».
>
> *adverbe* : « être complètement bienveillant ou totalement malveillant ».
>
> *et* : « un être bienveillant et au-delà ; un être malveillant, et pire encore ».
>
> *remplacer par un autre adjectif* : « un être fort bienveillant ».
>
> ---

*Mise à jour suite aux commentaires*

On est *dessus* comme on est *bienveillant*, on est situé à une place unique (physique pour dessus, morale pour bienveillant)  :

Comme on ne peut pas être *plus dessus*, on ne peut être *plus bienveillant*.

On est alors *au-dessus de* ou dans une situation que j'ai essayé de donner dans cette réponse.

---

P.S. : Pour passer de *bien* à *plus bien* on dit *meilleur*, pour passer de *meilleur* à *plus meilleur* on dit *parfait* : il y a une échelle, indépendante de l'étiquette grammaticale que l'on met sur le mot, et ce n'est pas parce que *...veillant* est accolé que cela change l'usage de l'échelle de comparaison qui utilise un mot différent pour chaque échelon.

En dessous, dessous, dedans, dessus, au-dessus fonctionne sur le même modèle

*Il faudrait inventer **meilleurveillant***.

Comment: Il est dans charte de ce site de justifier son vote négatif, au moins pour faciliter l'amélioration des réponses.

Comment: Oui, sinon c'est moins bienveillant. (mais plus sérieusement, oui, ça permet à celui qui a rédigé la réponse de l'améliorer si la critique est pertinente)

Comment: @cl-r Voilà donc la justification attendue : bienveillant et malveillant ne sont pas plus des comparatifs que grand, petit, malheureux ou bonhomme. C'est effectivement moins bienveillant de ne pas l'expliciter mais ça n'a pas de rapport avec plus pire ou davantage mieux.

Comment: @GAMPUB comment les qualifier alors ? Il y a une notion morale de *bien...* et de *mal...*, ne compare-t-on pas deux attitudes pour les fixer dans une échelle, et ce 'jugement' posé, on ne peut plus augmenter ou diminuer la position, pas plus qu'on peut être *plus dessus* (on est seulement *au-dessus*), on ne peut être *plus bienveillant*, mais dans une situation que j'ai essayé de définir dans ma réponse.

Comment: Meilleur est clairement un comparatif. « Ce gâteau est *meilleur* **que** l'autre. » se compare directement avec « Ce gâteau est *plus sucré* **que** l'autre. » et *plus meilleur* n'est pas une forme attendue dans un contexte normal. Par contre, *parfait* n'est pas un comparatif et pour autant *plus parfait* souffre des mêmes absences que *plus meilleur*. Il n'y a aucune difficulté à être moins *bienveillant* **que** Romain. Pour moi, *bienveillant* est un adjectif gradable qui ne pose pas du tout le problème que vous évoquer avec *dessus* (mais qui serait le même avec *supérieur*).

Comment: @GAMPUB Pour passer de *bien* à *plus bien* on dit *meilleur*, pour passer de *meilleur* à *plus meilleur* on dit* parfait* : il y a une échelle, indépendante de l'étiquette grammaticale que l'on met sur le mot, et ce n'est pas parce que *...veillant* est accolé que cela change l'usage de l'échelle de comparaison qui utilise un mot différent pour chaque échelon.En dessous, dessous, dedans, dessus, au-dessus fonctionne sur le même modèle.

Comment: @cl-r : [Ngrams](https://goo.gl/3uOs4h) de *plus bienveillant que* vs *plus dessus que*.

Comment: Je ne suis pas du tout d'accord. Bienveillant n'est absolument pas un comparatif, ni un mélioratif, c'est un adjectif "normal", ce n'est pas parce qu'il a le mot bien, qu'il a un rapport (voir ma réponse)

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Je conviens qu'il fait parti du langage soutenu, un peu vieilli. Une rapide recherche l'intégrait dans la formule *bien plus ... que*, plusieurs liens renvoient au même livre, un autre utilise *fort* à la place de plus ; mais en dehors des sites de français, il n'y a pas foule, et je n'ai pas souvenir de l'avoir entendu. J'ai tenu compte de vos remarque et modifié ma réponse en conséquence.

Comment: @Ngrams Certes... et j'ai modifié ma réponse, en fait je réponds pour proposer une réponse au capitaine Haddock, car je suis aussi gêné que lui par la proximité de *bien* et *plus*.

Comment: @Édouard Il y a peut-être dans ma réponse contre-versée et amendée une solution pour le capitaine... ou pas :)

Answer (score 0):

J'aimerais enfoncer deux portes ouvertes:

*plus bienveillant* n'a rien de choquant dans le cas de la négation.

Exemple :

> Ce garçon, autrefois affable, n'était alors plus bienveillant.

(Exemple cousu main, merci pour votre indulgence). Mais je suis loin du cas proposé...

En effet, « Je suis plus bienveillant que toi. » ressemblerait à une érudition de cour de récré qui, sans chercher la petite bête, appelle selon moi à, sinon une déconstruction, au moins un contournement.

Pourquoi pas :

> Je suis plus accommodant que toi.

ou, tenez,

> Je suis *mieux indulgent* que toi.

Ce ne sont pas les synonymes qui manquent dans notre jolie langue.

Les portes sont enfoncées, le bélier est vautré dans l'entrée.

Merci de ne pas sortir les mousquets face à mes tournures maladroites ; elles sont, disons, mon « p'tit jardin secret. »